# Invoice system normalization \ denormalization

Tags: postgresql

We have a two tables:

Invoices

[image]

And Invoice items

[image]

Each invoice has multiple items.

So my question is:
How performance, storage space and memory usage will change if we store the invoice **subtotal (each item price)** and **total (subtotal+tax)** in the invoice table, and get that fields by simple SELECT, or SUM the **price**s of each item to get the **subtotal** and SUM with **tax** to get the **total** by joining two tables?

Comment: Please [do not post code as images](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Given that an invoice has multiple items, how do you plan to store the subtotals *for each item* in the `invoice` table?

Answer (score 0):

## Performance

In terms of performance it is MUCH better to store these as fields in the invoice table at read time. However, each time an event occurs which changes these values you will need to update them, which slows down writes.

## Storage use

It of course takes much more space to store two values for each rows than not storing them.

## Memory usage

Memory usage is better if you have these values stored, because then you will not have to compute many totals at the same time and loading the values you need to sum under the hood

## Overall

It depends